# C# Microsoft Report Create dataset with query TableAdapter

Tags: c#, dataset, reportviewer

I'm creating quickly a report. I created a dataset in Visual Studio with drag and drop from the database.

At run-time I'm calling for each table the correspondent GetDataBy because I need two parameters. I read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171919.aspx

[image: DataSet with Query]

In my code to populate it I'm using the following code:

```
Reports.dsInventory inv = new Reports.dsInventory();

dsInventory.inventory_appointmentsDataTable dtAppointment = 
     new dsInventoryTableAdapters.inventory_appointmentsTableAdapter()
                                 .GetDataBy(PropertyId, AppointmentId);
dsInventoryTableAdapters.inventory_appointmentsTableAdapter taAppointments = 
     new dsInventoryTableAdapters.inventory_appointmentsTableAdapter();
taAppointments.Fill(inv.inventory_appointments);
```

I tought `inv` is filled by my query but obviously not. How can I apply my filter (for example `GetDataBy(PropertyId, AppointmentId)`) and add the result to my `inv` dataset?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the simple solution I found is

```
dsInventory.inventory_appointmentsDataTable dtAppointment = 
          new dsInventoryTableAdapters.inventory_appointmentsTableAdapter()
          .GetDataBy(PropertyId, AppointmentId);
inv.Tables["inventory_appointment"].Merge(dtAppointment);
```